# В bootstrap содержимое класса "col-6" нужно прижать вправо. Всю голову сломал

Tags: веб-программирование, вёрстка, bootstrap, выравнивание

Пробовал
display: float-right;
justify-content: right;

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И как по картинке можно понять в чем у вас проблема? возможно там в самом html нужно поставить toggle button последним элементом в контейнере